# Moving an object back to the original position and rotation

Tags: modeling, transform-orientation

I am finding it hard to move a copy of an object back to its original position.
How can I move the big object you see in the foreground back to the exact position and rotation you see the small object in the foreground at the center and aligned to the world origin?

Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it depends what you've donne with it, could you please share your file? what does it give if you put the 3D cursor on the one on the background, select the one on the foreground and put it on the 3D cursor? (with Shift S)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I don't know exactly what I have done these are just two parts of a larger project I have been working on for months.  I would need to know how to realign the object to when I first created it because I need to cut it and insert some pin cylinders for 3d printing.   I have uploaded the file as you recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select 2 faces of your object in *Edit* mode, create a custom orientation in the *Transform Orientations* panel:

[image]

Back to Object mode, enable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option:

[image]

Then *Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation*:

[image]

Disable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset the rotation, come back to *Global* orientation:

[image]

Then <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>90</kbd> to rotate 90° on Z, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Rotation*, select the small object and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*:

[image]

Then select the big one and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*:

[image]

Now their origin is at the same location:

[image]